# Filling a combobox with a dictionary as datasource when it uses uint and a custom class

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, combobox

Maybe anyone has an idea about how to get this to work:

My program is a dll which gets used by another program and gets its informations from there.

the dictionary is declared as the following:

```
public Dictionary<uint, Skill> Skills { get; }
```

and the class Skill is declared as the following:

```
    public class Skill
{
    public Skill(uint id, string name, string description, ushort levelRequired);

    public string Description { get; }
    public uint Id { get; }
    public ushort LevelRequired { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

My Goal is to get my combobox to fill it with the Skill's Name and use the ID as its value which i get with 'SelectedItem'

Hope someone can help me out on this, i belive i tried over 50 different methods i found on the web and here...

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have uint as dictionary key and, as I understand, the same uint in the class?

You can try to bind the "ItemsSource" property to your Dictionary (or Dictionary.Values), then bind the "DisplayMemberPath" property to "Name", and use "SelectedValuePath" to set ID as value.

[SelectedValuePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx)
[DisplayMemberPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public uint Value;

        public Item(string name, uint value)
        {
            Name = name; Value = value;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            // Generates the text shown in the combo box
            return Name;
        }
    }

 public Dictionary<uint, Skill> Skills = new Dictionary<uint, Skill>();
 private void FormTesting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Skill tempSkill= new Skill();
            tempSkill.Name = "test name";
            Skills.Add(1, tempSkill);

            foreach (uint val in Skills.Keys)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(new Item(Skills[val].Name,val));
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you .